# I could see osmnx has removed the function ox.extended_stats. Is there any other way to estimate these statistics?

Tags: networkx, openstreetmap, osmnx

I am working on network analysis and needed the metrics that can be estimated with the `ox.extended_stats` function. However, this function is deprecated now.

Is there any other way to calculate these statistics? Can we use older versions of libraries? How can it be done? I am relatively new to Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That function was deprecated for a while before it was eventually removed. Its deprecation warning stated:

> The extended_stats function has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Use NetworkX directly for extended topological measures.

As it suggests, that function was just a wrapper around a few different NetworkX functions. You can use NetworkX directly to calculate these network statistics.